# Script Always runs from / instead of current directory

Tags: bash, shell, ubuntu, scripting

So get this. I have been running my scripts with ./something.sh and sh something.sh for around 3 months now. These scripts have always ran from the directory that I launched them from.

Now all of a sudden my scripts don't work because they seem to launch from / instead of the current directory. For example lets say my script looks like this:

```
cd players

rm *
```

Instead of going into players it errors out because it can not find the folder "players" and then tries to remove the entire root file-system. (Lucky for me I don't run these as Sudo or Root).

Any ideas? This was working find before, and it just now started acting up!

Thanks!

Comment: where are you running your script from?

Comment: what you should do immediately is to change your script to be `rm players/*`. after that try to fix the problem.

Comment: mnagel is right.  But even better to use the full path:  `rm /path/to/players/*`

Comment: You can declare and export global variable used to create full path. It is easy to configure and change.

Comment: I would use full paths, but when I created the script (it is obviously bigger than what I put, I was just using this as an example) I needed to make it so I didn't have to change it no matter which directory I put it in. That's why I don't use Full Paths. It's just weird that it stopped work randomly. I will try these things and let everyone know if it worked. Still curious what happened though!

Comment: you can put echo 'pwd' at the beginning of script to make sure where your script is located when running. It gives you clue why script does not find player folder.

Comment: When I did that last night it seemed that is runs from "/" even though I'm launching it from /home/someone/somefolder

Answer (score 2):

For safety you can change your line to

```
cd players && rm *
```

It would only delete the contents of `players` if it was successfully able to change to it.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
cd ./players

rm *
```

Should work as expected!

Comment: I will try this, and if It works I will try rm players/*
Any ideas on what might have changed?

Comment: the '.' here refers to the current working directory and it was missing in your case.

Comment: `cd` already treats relative paths as relative to the current working directory. How does explicitly adding `./` help?

Answer (score 0):

I only can guess that your scripts now are started in a different manner; the most probable I can think of is that they are called by a cron job of a user which does not have a home directory (anymore) or similar.

But this really is a shot in the dark.  I propose to think more about how your scripts get started and investigate on that topic.

Comment: I wish I could say that I did change how I am starting them, but I haven't. :(

Comment: Something has changed.  You could help finding an answer by describing how you start the scripts.  Then I can take more educated guesses on what (updates, changes in the user data base, changes in the network access, …) has inflicted this situation.